# An apparent counterexample of the derivative proprety of Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, dirac-delta

I learned that one of the properties of the Fourier transform is that $\mathcal{F}[\frac{df}{dx}] = ik\mathcal{F}[f(x)]$. However it seems to me that the function $f(x) = 1$ is a counterexample of this property. Its Fourier transform is $2\pi\delta(k)$ but its deravitive is $0$ and the Fourier transform of $0$ is just $0$. So why it isn't?

Comment: The formula is proves under somewhat stringent conditions. It is not valid for $f(x)=1$.

Comment: From what I read on wikipedia, the conditions are that $f$ is absolutely continuous, differentiable, integrable, and with integrable derivative and it satisfies all of those properties.

Comment: $f(x)\equiv 1$ is not integrable.

Comment: Isn't it integrable because $x$ is an antiderivative of $1$?

Comment: "integrable" here does not mean "has an antiderivative". It means that its absolute value has a finite integral over the whole real line. In symbols, we say $f$ is integrable if $\int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(x)|dx < \infty$.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help.

Comment: However, there isn't a contradiction even if we accept the result as stated. this is because $k\delta(k)$ is identically equal to zero

Comment: @OfekTevet If you have trouble posting in English, try using [this](https://translate.google.com/)

Comment: Oh right, thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

There is no contradiction: on the left we have for $f=1$
$$ \mathcal F(f') = \mathcal F(\text{the zero function})=\text{the zero function}$$
and on the right we have
$$ ik\mathcal F(f)=i2\pi k \delta(k) = \text{the zero distribution}$$
The result holds for all [tempered distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform) $f\in\mathcal S'$. Proof follows, though it won't be intelligible if you don't know what a distribution is. Let $\phi$ be a [Schwartz function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space). Then:
\begin{align}
(\mathcal F(f'),\phi) = (f',\mathcal F\phi) = -(f,(\mathcal F\phi)')=(f,\mathcal F( ik\phi)) = (\mathcal Ff,ik\phi) =(ik\mathcal Ff,\phi),\ \text{QED.}
\end{align}
And also, the proof that $k\delta(k) = 0$: Let $\phi$ be Schwartz; then,
$$ (k\delta(k), \phi(k)) =  (\delta(k), k\phi(k))= k\phi(k)\Big|_{k=0} = 0,\ \text{QED.}$$

Comment: Thanks for all the help.